# unexpected Inifite loop using switch and some function

Tags: php

Basically I have a piece of code that has a switch statement and some functions. It goes to the switch statement using a parameter given by the browser "`?step=X`" and then selects the appropriate function.

My problem is even when at the end of each function I specify to go to the next switch statement it never does it and somehow it becomes an infinite loop of the function that I selected with the "step=x" in the browser...

Why is getting stuck in 1 function and not iterating through them? (the code for the step is highlighted at the end of the script)

I get the output in the browser of any selected function. so It enters the switch and the selected function... but then it becomes and infinite loop because in the broswer i get 300 of the same echo statements. It is never able to iterate through them or exit the selected function.

```
<?php 
//DB Config File
$dbFile = 'dbconfig.php';

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$server = $_GET['server'];
$dbname = $_GET['dbname'];
$step = $_GET["step"];





function createfile ($dbFile) {
        //Creates File and populates it.
        $fOpen = fopen($dbFile, 'w');
global $username, $password, $server, $dbname;
            $fString .= "<?php\n";
            $fString .= "// Database Constants\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_SERVER =" . "\"" . $server . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_USER =" . "\"" . $username . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_PASS =" . "\"" . $password . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "\$DB_NAME =". "\"" . $dbname . "\";\n";
            $fString .= "?>";

        fwrite($fOpen, $fString);
        fclose($fOpen);
return true;
}




try {
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=' .$server.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);

if ($db) { //if succesful at connecting to the DB

if (file_exists($dbFile)){
    if (is_readable($dbFile) && is_writable($dbFile)){ 

        //Creates File, populates it and redirects the user

    if (createfile($dbFile)) { 
    echo "nelxt";
    stepFunction($step);
    exit ();
            }


        } else { 

        echo "The file {$dbFile} cannot be accessed. Please configure the file manualy or grant Write and Read permission.";  }

    } else {

        //Creates File, populates it and redirects the user

    if (createfile($dbFile)) {

    echo "next";
        stepFunction($step);
    exit ();
            }

        }


}

} catch (PDOException $e) { //Catchs error if can't connect to the db.
    echo  'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Prepare SQL Statements
$IDB = $db->prepare( 
 "CREATE TABLE pages (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 subject_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  position int(3) NOT NULL,
  visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  content text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

$IDB2 = $db->prepare("
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  position int(3) NOT NULL,
  visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

$IDB3 = $db->prepare("
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  hashed_password varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

//Set Option to True or False
if (empty ($_GET['fot']) ) { 
    $fOT = false; 
    } else { $fOT = true;
        }

///////////////////////////////
// PROBLEMATIC STEP BEGINS HERE 
///////////////////////////////

function createTablePages (){

    global $db,$IDB;

                echo "0 <br>";
                stepFunction (1);

}
function createTableSubjects ($fOT){

    global $db,$IDB2;


                echo "1 <br>";
                stepFunction (2);
}

function createTableUsers ($fOT){

    global $db,$IDB3;
    echo "3 <br>";

}

function stepFunction ($step,$fOT){
global $db,$IDB1,$IDB2,$step,$fOT;



switch ($step) {
    case 0: echo "hola";
            createTablePages ($fOT);
            break;
    case 1: echo "hola2";
            createTableSubjects($fOT);
            break;
    case 2: createTableUsers ($fOT);
            break;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: It goes to the stepFunction function and gives the parameter 2 to it, which i hope is then passed to the switch statement... and go to the case 2...

Comment: Is everything ok about stepFunction having `$step,$fOT` and you calling it with `stepFunction (2)` (only 1 value instead of defined 2)?

Comment: Btw, `which` echo statements are you getting? :)

Comment: You saying that the `stepFunction` will never get parameters based in numbers because the selected variable is `$step`? EDIT: I took away the 2 parameters to only make it 1 parameter `$step` and is still giving the same results

Comment: if i put "`step=0`" i get output "hola 0" infinite times.... if i put `step=1` i get "hola2 1" and so on

Comment: @JonathanThurft aside from your question - do not use `global`. You are asking for troubles that way.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com what would you recommend to use?

Comment: @JonathanThurft - No, I did not say that. I just asked why you define functions with different amount of variables when you call them.

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius I don't follow. Could you give me an example please?

Comment: @JonathanThurft Pass all arguments to functions explicitly - if you got more than a few to pass, put them in array and pass that array (for simplicity). `Global` is very bad.

Comment: You have `function test($x)`. You call with `test(5, 'cow')`. It doesn't seem very ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix

```
function stepFunction ($step,$fOT){
global $db,$IDB1,$IDB2,$step,$fOT;
```

to

```
function stepFunction ($step){
global $db,$IDB1,$IDB2;
```

You are overriding your `$step` variable with the global one of the same name. Thus when you come with `?step=0` you call `stepFunction` with `0` then it goes to `createTablePages` then it goes to `stepFunction` with `1`, but is immediately replaced with 0 (because that's what the global `$step`'s value is) and again and again...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time :) Do you also think that the use of globals is bad and that i should use arrays to pass on variables to the function?

Comment: Yes, using globals is not advised. It is not necessary to pass variables as arrays unless you have a dynamic amount of them. Code would better readable if you send data in single variables than an array. Extracting them again will make the code look a bit ugly and less readable. P.S. as for the globals issue, use OOP and have public and private variables so for example your methods would be wrapped in one class and you would have $this->db accessible in any non-static method. Not only this would get rid of the constant need of redeclaration, but will also make your script more secure.